# How to change NPM scoped package to a github repo

Tags: github, npm, package, yarnpkg

I've forked a repository from @react-native-firebase/admob to my own github and made some changes to it, and I want to change the existing package.json to reflect the same.

previous:

```
 @react-native-firebase/admob: "6.3.1"
```

now I want it to be something like

```
 @react-native-firebase/admob: "https://github.com/[username]/[reponame]"
```

However it doesn't work, scoped package always seems to download from their own github repository.

Comment: Did you try this with packages that are not scoped and it worked?

Comment: yes it worked in normal packages when I added a #commitID at the end of the repo but it doesn't work for scoped packages and I'm still trying to figure out. There is no documentation for this as well :/

Comment: did you try changing the scope to '@my-user'  or '@my-org' , publish it to your own private github package repo and import as '@my-org/admob' ?